# How to bin/score based on sort order percentile

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to give different cities a "score" from 1 to 5 based on multiple different criteria to eventually add up the scores and make a decision about which city is the best.

The table "international_tobacco_alcohol" contains values of the percentage of income that residents spend on alcohol and tobacco. I want to sort the results into 5 bins where 1 is the lowest percentage spending, 5 is the highest.

I added a "sort_order" column

```
ALTER TABLE international_tobacco_alcohol ADD COLUMN sort_order INT DEFAULT NULL;

SET @x = 0;
UPDATE international_tobacco_alcohol SET sort_order = (@x:=@x+1) 
ORDER BY spent_on_alcohol_and_tobacco;
SELECT * FROM international_tobacco_alcohol;
```

And then I wanted to add the column "score" but I don't know how to do it correctly. I have tried basically every variation I can think of:

```
ALTER TABLE international_tobacco_alcohol ADD COLUMN score INT DEFAULT NULL;
UPDATE international_tobacco_alcohol 
SET score = CASE
        WHEN sort_order < .2*MAX(sort_order) THEN 1
        WHEN sort_order=> .2*MAX(sort_order)and <.4*MAX(sort_order) THEN 2
        WHEN sort_order=> .4*MAX(sort_order)and <.6*MAX(sort_order) THEN 3
        WHEN sort_order=> .6*MAX(sort_order)and <.8*MAX(sort_order) THEN 4
        WHEN sort_order=> .8*MAX(sort_order)and =<MAX(sort_order) THEN 5
        END;
```

I want the CASE WHEN clause to be in proportion to the total number of rows, not a predefined value, so that it can be recreatable and used with new data.

I appreciate some help. If I could create the score without the intermediate step of creating the "sort_order" column that would be great too.
`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the [sort_order] by [spent_on_alcohol_and_tobacco].
An alternative is to use RANK() function or DENSE_RANK();

I don't know the columns but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT [col_1], [col_2]
    ,RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY [Location] ORDER BY [spent_on_alcohol_and_tobacco] DESC) AS Rank
FROM [international_tobacco_alcohol]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Window functions aren't implemented in MySQL.